# Tool do analyze web traffic per file and time period?

Tags: web-server, log-files

For a web site which uses Analog to create a daily web server statistic, I am looking for a tool which can read the log files and report weekly / monthly downloads (or page hits) for individual addresses / files to analyze trends over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a look at
http://www.webalizer.com

I couldn't remember the names, now i found them:

http://piwik.org/

http://www.w3perl.com/

http://www.crawltrack.net/

Maybe it can help

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried goaccess?, seems to be a quite handy tool and really fast, especially if you want to run it on the terminal. http://goaccess.prosoftcorp.com/

Answer (score 1):

awstats? it's simple... but i believe it can helps you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can either use [Splunk>](http://www.splunk.com). It has useful web interface and rich capabilities of gathering info from different sources, filtering it, structuring and making reports.

Answer (score 0):

The best advise I can offer is to learn Perl. With that you can extract anything you want from any of your logs with ease. Of course as a sysadmin I would expect you already use Perl, as well as other similar tools.